# The leftbar environment and enumerate

Tags: formatting, mdframed, exam, framed

I'm looking to work on my homework template, and I've come to a wall. I'm trying to make the `leftbar` environment from the `mdframed` package work with the `questions` environment such that the bar is directly under the above paragraph, instead of automatically aligning to the left margin. Any suggestions?

Attached is what I've got so far, and as you can see the bar is aligned left, whereas I want the bar to be in that empty space just before the solution and right under part (a).

EDIT: Here's what I've got so far

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\usepackage{amsfonts,titlesec,titling,fontspec,fontspecxetex,lipsum,framed,mdframed,mathtools,txfonts}

\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}
\usepackage[sans]{dsfont}
\usepackage[framed]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in, includefoot, footskip=30pt]{geometry}
\newcommand{\answer}[1]{\begin{leftbar}{\footnotesize\textbf{\textsf{SOLUTION}}{\normalsize #1}}\end{leftbar}}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright}
            {\theauthor}    \\
            {\thedate}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}\,\,\vline height 16pt depth 10pt
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushleft}
            \,\,\textbf{\thetitle}  \\
            \,\,{\theclass}
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage} 
\end{center}
}

\title{\textsf{Homework \#}}
\author{\textsf{Name}}
\date{\textsf{Month Day, Year}}
\newcommand{\theclass}{\textsf{Class}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{questions}
    \question{
        \lipsum[1]
        \begin{parts}
            \part{
                \lipsum[2]
                \answer{
                    \lipsum[3]
                }
            }
        \end{parts}
    }
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Sorry for not including that earlier--- first post here :P

[image: Homework PDF]

Comment: It would be great if you could  post your code to show what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: @Andrew added! :) thanks, and sorry about that

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... you meant that the `leftbar` should align with the sublist, i.e., `(a)`, am I correct? Please excuse if I'm wrong...

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If I can automatically align the leftbar to whichever environment it's nested in, that would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the \leftbar environment (or in this case \answer) inside a minipage of width textwidth will cause the left bar to follow the itemized indentation and be placed directly under the paragraph above.

```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{leftbar}
        \lipsum[3]
    \end{leftbar}
\end{minipage}
```